# Playing with the Python zip function

Tags: python

Say I wanted to find "greater than" in 2 lists.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0, 0.1, 4]
map( <something>, zip(a,b))
```

I tried operator module. It has a operator.gt() method. But i couldn't find a way to make use of it with zip. any ideas? Edit: The output is just a True value if any one of the them is True.

thanks

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Are you trying to filter the list to contain only elements greater than a value?

Comment: hi, sorry, i edited my question. Just a true value if ANY one of the fits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To just compare the items in lists `a` with items in `b`, you don't event have to use `zip()`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3] 
>>> b = [0, 0.1, 4]
>>> map(operator.gt, a, b)
[True, True, False]
>>>
```

But on the other hand you've not specified what kind of output you're expecting.

**EDIT:**

To effectively `OR` the result, wrap it with `any()`. Like so:

```
>>> any(map(operator.gt, a,b))
True
```

Comment: good one, +1, now I know that map accepts not just one sequence

Answer (score 2):

```
In [6]: a = [1,2,3]

In [7]: b = [0, 0.1, 4]

In [8]: [max(a_,b_) for a_,b_ in zip(a,b)]
Out[8]: [1, 2, 4]
```

or, pithier,

```
In [9]: map(max, zip(a,b))
Out[9]: [1, 2, 4]
```

If you want of list of `True/False` values (`True` where the item in `a` is greater than the item in `b`, and `False` otherwise), you could use [itertools.starmap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) with [operator.gt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.gt):

```
In [15]: import itertools as IT

In [17]: list(IT.starmap(operator.gt, zip(a,b)))
Out[17]: [True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [0, 0.1, 4]

map (max, zip(a,b))

Output: [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy is ideal for this kind of stuff if you don't mind the additional dependancy.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([0, 0.1, 4])
c = a > b
```